# How to display French in the language Section of App Store for my app?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, french

I have successfully released my app on the App Store but the language displayed in the App information is English despite the fact that I have selected French as the primary language for my app when I submitted it.

Any idea how to display French in the language section of the App Store ?

Comment: What makes you think that's a software issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide French localization for your app to have `French` included as your app's languages. Open the project Info page in Xcode, and double check the `Localization` settings.

It should show something like: `Base`, `English`, `French`, etc... in the list. If `French` is not in there, add it, and write the text translations manually in `.strings` file for example.

The languages that you add (or set as primary) on App Store Connect while submitting the app for review is only usable for setting localized App Store app descriptions, promotional texts, tags, or screenshots for different languages. It's basically for advertising purposes only.